# Does visual studio includes only aspx.cs files in dll which are having same namespace of project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2012. I have created a directory named "Handler" inside my project and added an aspx file along with .cs file (both downloaded from a third party tool) to it. All code is working fine.

Now, I have published project to another directory. In published directory I have marked that the in side "Handler" folder aspx page is there but not the .cs page.

Now, when ever I am requesting the aspx page inside "Handler", I am getting error 404 xxxx.aspx page not found. Now, if I am coping the path and hit the url for that page then I am getting error that xxxx.aspx.cs file not found.

As per my best knowledge, whenever we build the project, all the code will build to dll in bin folder. Then why this file is required .cs file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on the attributes of the @Page directive of your aspx page

I guess your third party page `@page` directive holds a `CodeFile` attribute.

`CodeFile` attribute states that, even though the `.aspx.cs` gets compiled (let's say it just gets checked) in Visual Studio, the result of the compilation will not be put in the dll resulting of the build.

The `.aspx.cs` will be compiled, along with the `.aspx` upon first invocation.
This allows to edit your deployed `aspx.cs` and have the result available immediately (which can be seen as handy, or risky)

> As per my best knowledge, whenever we build the project, all the code
>   will build to dll in bin folder. Then why this file is required .cs
>   file?

This is the case when being in the default case, having a CodeBehind attribute in the page directive,instead of a CodeFile attribute

See CodeBehind and CodeFile attributes in [documentation for @Page element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Note that you can use CodeFile attribute in Web Application Projects. I do it all the time.

Comment: Thanks.. :) before reading this answer, I just have replace the attribute CodeFile to CodeBehind and my problem was solved. But I was not sure if it was due to this change. Again thanks a lot.. :)